$F(x,y)$ absolutely irreducible over the rationals, but reducible modulo infinitely many primes?
In this two page note we give efficient probabilistic algorithm for factoring bivariate
polynomials in composite characteristic assuming the solution is unique
and we would like to test the algorithm on more data.
Let $F(x,y)$ be polynomial with integer coefficients absolutely irreducible over
extensions of the rationals.

Q1 Which $F$ are reducible modulo infinitely many primes?


None. This is well-known and can be seen either as a variant of Bertini's theorem, or as a consequence of the completeness of the first-order theory of algebraically closed fields of fixed characteristic.

@ArnoFehm Many thanks. Probably will delete the question.
